# android draw line betwen array of points crossing line between start to end

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, overlay, geopoints

i have done this:

```
public class LongTravlOverlay extends Overlay{
    private Projection projection;
    private List<GeoPoint> glist;

    GeoPoint gP1; 
    GeoPoint gP2;
    public LongTravlOverlay(Projection a,List<GeoPoint> b){
        projection=a;
        this.glist=b;
    }   
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){
        super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);

        Paint   mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        for(GeoPoint g1:glist)
        {
            if(gP1!=null)
            {
                gP1=gP2;
                gP2=new GeoPoint(g1.getLatitudeE6(),g1.getLongitudeE6());
            }
            else
            {
                gP1=new GeoPoint(g1.getLatitudeE6(),g1.getLongitudeE6());
                gP2=gP1;
                continue;
            }
        Point p1 = new Point();
        Point p2 = new Point();
        Path path = new Path();

        projection.toPixels(gP1, p1);
        projection.toPixels(gP2, p2);

        path.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
        path.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);

        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

It works and draws the line between all the points.
The only problem is between the first point and the last point there is also a line that ends up crossing on the path of the other points.
How do i remove it?

Answer (score 0):

You have your geopoints gP1 and gP2 as instance variables. `draw` will be called multiple times.

At the end of your iterations on the first call to `draw`, `gP2` is the last point. At the first iteration of the second and subsequent calls to `draw`, `gP1` is assigned to the last point and `gP2` is assigned to your first point. This draws a line between the first and last point. To rectify this, just declare those variables in `draw` or initialize it to null before iterating through your geopoints.

```
gP1 = null;
gP2 = null;
for(GeoPoint g1:glist) {
//Drawing logic
}
```